# How to change `solid color` from the code?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have a `Shape` defined in `xml`. Now I need to change a `solid color` from the code, could you please advice how?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#000000"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
        android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this in my code

```
GradientDrawable myGrad = (GradientDrawable)rectangle.getBackground();
myGrad.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Hope this helps :)

EDIT: for `GradientDrawable` instead of `ShapeDrawable`

Comment: I've got ClassCastException because GradientDrawable can't be cast to ShapeDrawable, but finally I got it working skipping the `getPaint()` method, just set color. Please modify an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: 08-11 15:08:51.911: E/AndroidRuntime(2906): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.LayerDrawable cannot be cast to android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable
So not work

Comment: @user3111850 For `LayerDrawable`, you should not change the color with `GradientDrawable`, because the `LayerDrawable` is not instanceof `ShapeDrawable`

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem when I set the background of the item(in the listview)the shape defined in xml, I've got ClassCastException when I invoke the convertview's getBackground() method, but when I invoke the item's outest view's  getBackground() method,the Exception disappear, the problem resolved.