# How to change stroke color dynamically?

Tags: android, android-studio, shapes

(Sorry for my language, I'm french)

I need to change the `stroke color` of a Shape.
I've the same problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16775891/how-to-change-solid-color-from-the-code).
I need to change solid color when the EditText is not correct.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
        android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="2px" android:color="#CCCCCC"/>
</shape>
```

The answer :

```
GradientDrawable myGrad = (GradientDrawable)rectangle.getBackground();
myGrad.setColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Problem in the answer is, I don't understand the **rectangle** item.
If I replace it by the EditText, it is applied to the background, not the solid background.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT : My Bad, i want to change the **Stroke** color, not solid.

Comment: you mean border is not visible??

Comment: Yes it's visible, he's Black. I need to change the color to red.

Comment: I think you are confusing stroke with solid. Try my ans and let me know if you are looking for something else.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
GradientDrawable myGrad = (GradientDrawable)rectangle.getBackground();
myGrad.setStroke(2, Color.RED);
```

Comment: can you change only the color and keep the original stroke width?

Comment: When setting the stroke width and color you probably have to be careful about density.  I don't think myGrad.setStroke(2, Color.RED) is the same as "2dp"